# Displaying django-cms submenu in an option element

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, django-cms

I'm using django-cms as i'm outputting the sub menu on each template which is displayed in an ul. However I'm making the site reponsive and i'd like to be able to output the content within a select dropdown. Here are the docs - http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/navigation.html#show-sub-menu It mentions using a custom template but I don't really need to do that.

I would like to output the sub menu like so:

```
<select>
<option> Home </option>

</select>
```

Rather than..

```
<ul>
<li> Home </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I've actually managed to do it using some JS. I've converted the `<li>` tags to `<option>` here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.subnav').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
                            var $option = $('<option />');
                            $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
                            $("#mobileNav").append($option);
                    });
                });
                $("#mobileNav").change(function(){
                    window.location.href = $(this).val();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I will try your solution now as it's much cleaner, but the code above could be handy for someone else in the future.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, the documentation tells you to use a custom template, which is exactly what you should do in this case.

```
<select>
    {% show_sub_menu 1 "option_menu.html" %}
</select>
```

Then in "option_menu.html":

```
{% for child in children %}
    <option>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Note this will only show one level of sub-menu, for more, check `{% if child.children %}` and if it is `True`, do what you think is best in your case.